# Обновление токена в React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Кто-нибудь реализовывал обновление access токена в React?
Не пойму, как правильно реализовать данный функционал.

Мне с бека приходит access токен, который я устанавливаю в localStorage  и по истечении его срока жизни ловлю ошибку 401 и делаю action для получения нового, но как повторить неуспешный запрос, на котором поймал 401 ошибку?!

Мой обработчик fetch запроса:

```
export const fetchData = (
    url,
    callback,
    headers = fetchHeaders(),
    method = 'GET',
    body = null,
) => {
    let domain = ...

    let addCredentials =
        url === '/authorize' || url === '/auth/logout'
            ? { credentials: 'include' }
            : null

    let request = () =>
        fetch(`${domain}${url}`, {
            ...addCredentials,
            method,
            headers,
            body: body,
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                    return res.json()
                } else {
                    throw res
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
                    if (res.status === 'failure') {
                        notie.alert({ type: 'error', text: res.message })
                        throw new Error(res)
                    }
                    if (res.error) {
                        notie.alert({ type: 'error', text: res.error })
                        throw new Error(res)
                    }
                }
                return callback(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (err.status === 401 && url !== '/authorize') {
                    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: AuthType.SET_AUTH,
                        login: true,
                        accessToken: '',
                    })
                    request()
                } else if (err.status === 500) {
                    notie.alert({
                        type: 'error',
                        text: 'Ошибка при обращении к серверу произошла ошибка',
                    })
                }
            })

    return request()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я еще не реализовывал, но мысль такая:

Есть компонент, который отвечает за токены, обновляя так, чтоб *всегда* был валидный токен. Он не ждет, пока какой-то *обычный* запрос завалится с 401.

Есть компонент, который отвечает за надежную доставку *изменений*.
Ему в очередь можно класть изменения.
Если у нас не 2хх, или отвалился wifi -- будет формировать запросы и перепосылать (это не всегда лучше).

Обычные компоненты могут использовать либо сервис надежной доставки, либо посылать *обычныe* запросы. Зависит от того, что ожидает пользователь, у которого отвалился wifi:

- я напечатал, а оно само записывается
- или нажал, ничего не случилось, нажму еще

Общаться они могут через `useContext`.

Comment: Если не ждать, "пока какой-то обычный запрос завалится с 401", то не проще будет в саге-наблюдателе поставить интервал по времени жизни на обновление токена после авторизации?

Comment: Я именно редукс/саги не использовал. Звучит как примерно то же.

Comment: здесь смысл, что надежных запросов не бывает. И отвечает за перепосыл либо фронтовый компонент, либо пользователь. И м. б. через раз.

Comment: а токены -- отдельная ответственность

Comment: Понял, вас, спасибо за ответы, решил при помощи axios.interseptors.